How to setup RLS filter in Superset for dynamic data
I have a simple table in DB with 2 columns, name and phone.
"Sachin"    "9988776655"
"Ramesh"    "1988776655"
"Jadeja"    "2988776655"
"Karan"     "3988776655"

I created a dataset using this table. I created a chart using that dataset (Raw data Table). Works. Now the requirement is to create dynamic embedded dashboard links where based on the user logging in, I want the data to be shown in that chart.
So I set up a RLS filter. I applied following clause
name='{{ rls.user_name }}'

Now, I generated the guest token like so (to be called by logged in user Ramesh - so only his entry should show up):
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8088/api/v1/security/guest_token/" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJ......VeeYR6x6Ug" \
  -d '{
    "user": {
      "username": "guest",
      "first_name": "guest",
      "last_name": "user"
    },
    "resources": [{
      "type": "dashboard",
      "id": "3"             
    }],
    "rls": [{
      "clause": "user_name",
      "value": "Ramesh"
    }]
  }'

I get the token in response, which I create the embedded link with, and the chart shows up nothing in it.
Clearly, I'm not setting the RLS filter correctly. Where I'm going wrong? Is this not the use case that RLS filter can solve?

"rls": [{
"clause": "user_name",
"value": "Ramesh"
}]
can you try like this
**"rls": [{
  "clause": "user_name = 'Ramesh'"
}]**

